# Reading Sheet2 via Google Sheets API & Python

Tags: python, google-api

I just wanna read the next tab/sheet via the API in my Google Sheets Project with Python (Windows 10) Everything works for sheet1, I just want to read/edit sheet2 (and others that I will create in the project).

Tab example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ee9.jpg

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_penny.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

penny = client.open('pennystocks').sheet1

print(penny.get_all_records())
```

This works: penny = client.open('pennystocks').sheet1

This doesn't: penny = client.open('pennystocks').sheet2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to use the sheet except for the sheet of 1st tab using gspread.

  - For example, when there are 2 sheets of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" in a Spreadsheet, you want to use "Sheet2".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
penny = client.open('pennystocks').sheet1
```

#### To:

```
penny = client.open('pennystocks').worksheet('Sheet2')
```

#### Note:

- `client.open('pennystocks').sheet1` is open the 1st index of sheet. So for example, in your Spreadsheet, when the index of "Sheet1" is modified to "Sheet2", `client.open('pennystocks').sheet1` returns "Sheet2".

#### Reference:

- [Selecting a Worksheet](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yea baby! That's it! Thanks! I was looking in the wrong place, I thought I could find it on the Google API code site, but it's a gspread thing. I'm new at Python - I gotta remember each "module" has it's own set of rules.

Comment: @Biks Wigglesworth Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.